# Hover and current state with overlapping images?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, navigation

I am working with jquery UI tabs to make a tabbed navigation. It has active and hover both stages when the background color should be white. I managed to get this ok, but when I'm hovering the element right beside the current element, a small portion of my arrows' background isn't changing to white but staying blue. You'll understand the program when you see the demo that I'm working on here: 
http://arbabpolypackltd.com/erdem/ . It is supposed to look like this:

[image]

. Please help!! thanks!

Comment: Can you upload the image to the post instead of adding a link.  Plus should this actually be tagged with Java?

Comment: OOps I meant to tag it with javascript!!!!

Answer (score 0):

The reason that the blue is showing is that the individual nav containers are not extending far enough to the left (to be overlaid with the nav item to their left):

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but how do I extend the containers?